# How would I write a use case for making a payment via card or bank transfer

Tags: uml, use-case

"Any payment can be done either via credit/debit card or bank transfer."

Here's what I I'm thinking

[image]

Comment: Generalization with UCs is generally (pun intended) a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You mix use case, workflow and business rules. Say like that, you have one use case only : "make a payment".

But you should provide more details maybe.

Comment: Probably this one of those cases where the `<<extend>>` makes sense and you can extend `Make payment` by `Pay by credit` and `... debit`.

Comment: But if the extending UC  or included UC is not linked to an actor or to another UC it is not needed to show it on a UC diagram no ? If you do that , it's a way to show a sort of process and that's not the goal of a UC diagram no ?...

Comment: As I said "probably". I always recommend to not use incl/excl. Here is a way that you can show on a UC level that the system is extensible. You can show that you have different opportunities/options. And in that case it makes sense (to me). Credit and debit are both complex UCs involving different payment channels. And they add different values.